# Linking tables in SQLite 3 in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have to create a program which stores people's account details in a table in SQLite 3. One of the columns is interests, which is the user's favourite genre of film to watch. I then need to give them film recommendations based on that genre, so I need to have another table which stores films of that genre. The only problem is that I don't know how to link tables, so when comedy is their favourite genre, how to output films in the genre comedy.

Here is my code for adding a new user:

```
    #function for creating a new customer's account
def create_id(username, password, name, address, DoB, gender, interestsUp, recent1, recent2, recent3, recent4, recent5, recent6, recent7, recent8, recent9, recent10):
    #When adding something to a SQLite file, you have to put "" around each item
    c.execute('INSERT INTO userId(username,password,name,address,DoB,gender,interests, recent1, recent2, recent3, recent4, recent5, recent6, recent7, recent8, recent9, recent10) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (username, password, name, address, DoB, gender, interestsUp, recent1, recent2, recent3, recent4, recent5, recent6, recent7, recent8, recent9, recent10))#When adding something thats in a variable you put question marks and the name of the variables in brackets
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: If you display some code that illustrates what you've tried, you will probably receive more specific answers to help you. Are you familiar with SQL? You have the right idea -- another table containing film titles is good. You probably should also have a separate table for genre based on your indicated needs. So you'd probably have "films" and "genre" tables. That way you can store the genre index that matches "comedy" for example in the user table under "interests". And you would query the "films" table to give the user a list of films that match their genre selection.

Comment: @RonNorris I know I have to user a foreign key, I just don't know how to make that.

Comment: You need a join - http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-inner-join/

Comment: @Alan How does a join lead to connecting one table with another by the value of Comedy or Horror?

Comment: The table design you're using violates normal forms 1 through 4. You might start by normalizing your tables. If you don't, each step after this will be harder and harder.

Answer (score 4):

You should not try to store all data in one table. You should use a table for each topic (e.g. user details, interests) and then express a relationship between the tables. You can do this at design time with a foreign key, which will help with keeping the data clean, but you will also need to define the relationship when extracting the data.

Here's an example:

Table 1: Users
user_id, username

Table 2: User_Details
user_id, password, name, address, DoB, gender

Table 3: Favourites
fav_id, user_id, genre

Table 4: Films
film_id, film_name, genre

To get a list of a user's preferred genre would then be:

```
SELECT Films.film_name
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Favourites ON Users.user_id = Favourites.user_id
INNER JOIN Films ON Favourites.genre = Films.genre
WHERE user_id = ?
```

Nearly all the filtering here is done by the INNER JOIN. This will connect tables but only return results which are present in both tables. This means if a user has not yet submitted any preferences, no results will be returned for that user. The `ON` instruction tells the database what the relation is.

The output will be a list of films associated with any genres the user has favourited.